# Confusing text on review buttons

Tags: discussion, design, review

I've just had a confusing few moments in the review view where the "allowing" buttons read `Edit and Reopen` and `Reopen`. The confusion came from seeing the edit difference below and thinking that this is a valid edit and it *should* be edited like that and reopened. But just the "Reopen" button suggested to me that I would not be agreeing with the edit below.

[image]

Perhaps the button text could be less ambiguous?

Comment: To be clear, "Reopen" means "the post is good enough to be reopened; it should be reopened as-is". "Edit and Reopen" means "I can edit the post to make it good enough to be reopened; it should be reopened once I edit it".

Answer (score 2):

You confusion does not lie within the buttons but within the part left of them. There, it says clearly:

> This post **was *edited*** after it was closed. Should it be reopened? (Bolding mine, italics present in original)

As the text says, the edit you see was *already applied.* You are asked whether the results of the edit makes the post reopen worthy. Note that contrary to the suggested edit review, nowhere is there any mention of ‘approving an edit’.

Indeed, if you click *edit and reopen,* you will apply an additional edit *on top of the one already applied one* and further drop a reopen vote.